# Can not delete row using a ResultSet when the Query orders the database

Tags: java, derby

I'm using a Java Embedded Derby Database, and up until this point have been able to get everything I need to work working.

My error arises as such:

```
'deleteRow' not allowed because the ResultSet is not an updatable ResultSet.
```

How I retrieve my result set is in the following method:

```
private void getResultSet(){
        try{
            stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from guest_book order by date, name");
            rs.first();            
        }catch (SQLException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
        }
}
```

EDIT: my question is more of how should I go about implementing a way to organize my database, because I delete rows based off of the order they appear in in a `JTable`

I'm going to say that this is getting thrown because `ResultSet` Updatable only works on simple `SELECT` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing like that:

1. Get your `ResultSet`;
2. Do your custom logic (the one decides if the row should be deleted);
3. Save IDs of all entries needs to be deleted
4. Perform a separate query with all these ids (or, in worst case, a separate delete query for each ID);

You may find [this article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/batchupdate.html) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "Select * ...." command.
Use "Select column1,column2,.. ".
Then check
I am sure it will not show any error